# Dynamically add javascript for validating phone numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am working on a project which has already gone live and now there are some fixes required. Apparently I need to add conditional javascript/jquery code to validate phone number field. But my problem is that the developers have used `CommModeID/CommValues` pair for phone/email and same for contact person's phone/email too. I need to apply a class dynamically to the fields when the CommModeID = 1. Can anyone help me how to achieve this in this following code. Right now I am not able to understand how should I do it because the project is vast and I am new to this project.

Model:

```
public class ShipperEmail
{
        [Key]
        public int CommShipperID { get; set; }
        public int ShipperContactID { get; set; }
        public string Person { get; set; }
        public string CommName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must be Select")]
        public int CommModeID { get; set; }
        public string CommMode { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must be entered")]
        public string CommValues { get; set; }
        public bool isPrimary { get; set; }
        public string flag { get; set; }
        public int? RelationID { get; set; }
        public int? TimeZoneId { get; set; }
        public string PreferredTimeFrom { get; set; }
        public string PreferredTimeTo { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IList<Writer.Repository.Models.ShipperEmail>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"><button type="button" id="btnclose" class="close-link close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>
</div>        

@{ int i = 0; }
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmEditShippercontacts" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row mar-none" id="pnl-emailaddresscomps">
        <input type="hidden" name="ShipperID" value="@ViewData["ShipperID"]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ShipperContactID" value="@ViewData["ShipperContactID"]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Self" value="@ViewData["Self"]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="CommTypeID" value="@ViewData["CommTypeID"]" />
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="datarw">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ShipperContactID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CommShipperID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].flag, new { @id = "flag" })
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].CommModeID, new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["SysCommMode"], "Value", "Text", Model[i].CommModeID), new { @class = "form-control input-md" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].CommValues, new { htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "form-control input-md" } } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].CommValues, "", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "text-danger" } })
                                <div class="input-group-btn no-pad">
                                    <div id="Addemailpluse">
                                        <button href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm add-btn @(i == 0 ? "btnAddEmail" : "Emailremove-btn") " type="button"><i class="fa  @(i == 0 ? "fa-plus" : "fa-minus") "></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
                            <div class="input-sm pad-none">
                                <div class="checkbox mar-none">
                                    <label>
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].isPrimary, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "isPrimaryEmail" } }) Primary
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right m-t-sm">@I18N("Save")</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function fnBindEvsAC() {

            $('.datarw input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                        if (this.checked) {
                            $(this).prop('checked', false);
                            $(this).parent('.icheckbox_square-orange').removeClass('checked');
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    $(this).parent('.icheckbox_square-orange').addClass('checked');
                } else {
                    if ($('#pnl-emailaddresscomps .isPrimaryEmail:checked').length == 0) {

                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                        alert("@I18N("Atleast one record should be set as Primary.")");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).parent('.icheckbox_square-orange').removeClass('checked');
                    }
                }
            });            

            if ($('#pnl-emailaddresscomps .isPrimaryEmail:checked').length == 0) {
                $('#pnl-emailaddresscomps .isPrimaryEmail:first').prop('checked', true);
            }

            var form = $("#mdlAddEdit form");
            form.removeData('validator');
            form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        }
        fnBindEvsAC();
        var idxdatarw = "@i";
        $('.btnAddEmail').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var $dr = $('#pnl-emailaddresscomps .datarw').eq(0).clone().find("#hidenemail,#EmailAddress").val("").end();
            $dr.find('input,select').each(function () {
                this.name = this.name.replace('[0]', '[' + idxdatarw + ']');
                this.id = this.id.replace('_0_', '_' + idxdatarw + '_');

                var $valmsg = $(this).siblings('.field-validation-valid');
                if ($($valmsg).length > 0) {
                    var stvalmsg = $($valmsg).attr('data-valmsg-for');
                    $($valmsg).attr('data-valmsg-for', stvalmsg.replace('[0]', '[' + idxdatarw + ']'));
                }
            });
            $($dr).find('input[type="text"],textarea').val("");
            $($dr).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
            $($dr).find('input[id^="flag"]').val('I');
            $($dr).find('.btnAddEmail').addClass('Emailremove-btn');
            $($dr).find('.btnAddEmail').find("i").removeClass("fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-minus");
            $('#pnl-emailaddresscomps').append($dr);
            fnBindEvsAC();
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".Emailremove-btn", function () {
            if ($(this).closest(".datarw").find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 1) {
                alert('Remove primary then try again..!')
            } else {
                $(this).closest(".datarw").find('input[id^="flag"]').val('D');
                $(this).closest(".datarw").hide();
            }
        });

        $('form#frmEditShippercontacts').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).valid()) { return; }
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Success) {
                        toastr.success("@I18N("Contact detail saved successfully.")");
                        $('.webui-popover.ShipperContact.in').hide();
                        if (data.Result.Data) {
                            var commVal = data.Result.Data.value;
                            var commtype = data.Result.Data.CommType;
                            var Self = data.Result.Data.Self;
                            if (commtype == "@((int)UtilityEnums.SysCommType.Email)") {
                                if (Self) { $('#selfEmailID').html(commVal); } else { $('#PEmail').html(commVal); }
                            }
                            else if (commtype == "@((int)UtilityEnums.SysCommType.Mobile)") {
                                if (Self) { $('#selfMobile').html(commVal); } else { $('#PMobileupd').html(commVal); }
                            }
                            fnReloadMoveSummary();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.webui-popover.ShipperContact.in .webui-popover-content').html(data.Result);
                    }
                    btnClosePopups();
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $('.webui-popover.ShipperContact.in').hide();
                    toastr.error("@I18N("Contact details not saved.")");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShipperDetailsForMove(int id, int asid = 0)
    {
        ShipperContactPerson data = new ShipperContactPerson();
        data = _shipperService.GetShipperCP(id);
        if (data.PShipperContactID == null)
        {
            data.ContactPerson = data.ShipperName;
            data.PEMailID = data.EmailId;
            data.PMobile = data.Mobile;
        }
        IEnumerable<Document> DocumentData = _spMoveService.GetDocumentList(id, data.DestinationCountryID == null ? 0 : data.DestinationCountryID, 3);
        ViewData["DocumentList"] = DocumentData;
        IEnumerable<Communication> CommunicationData = _spMoveService.GetCommunicationData(id).Where(x => x.AccountTypeID == 3);
        ViewData["CommunicationData"] = CommunicationData;
        ViewData["asid"] = asid;
        return View(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

could you not just put a pattern on the input?
filter it before it gets submitted?

ie

```
\+\d{11}
```

would respond to +614123123 etc
alternatively, without the international code

```
(\+\d{11})|(\d{10})
```

would reply to 0412312312

Comment: the problem is not the script... I have to put this script `$('.PhoneNumber1').on('keypress', function(event){
              console.log(event.keyCode)
           var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
            if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
                        return true;
                    } else if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                });` but conditionally. How to put conditional javascript on commId values?

Comment: Im afraid i cant be too much help here, my java knowledge is limited, 
but could you not pass the commId value to a var ie.


   `var commid = $('.PhoneNumber1').val();`


then feed that var through the conditional javascript (ie, with the if blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
function checkPhone(phone) {
        return /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/.test(phone);
    }
```

Comment: the problem is not the script... I have to put this script `$('.PhoneNumber1').on('keypress', function(event){
              console.log(event.keyCode)
           var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
            if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
                        return true;
                    } else if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                });` but conditionally. How to put conditional javascript on commId values?